# How can I save global property from XML response via XPath in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I join team where SoapUI as SOAP client and there is authentication step which produces access token. Each subsequent request should be populated with this token.

It means that I manually replace old access token with new.

At first I create global property via `File => Preference` and this allows me to perform *only one edit per day* but I like get rid of any manual steps at all.

I am not fully understand SoapUI, we don't use testsuites / cases.

How can I create something that in one click perform request, extract value via XPath from response and save it in global properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I faced is absence of knowledge how to use SoapUI.

So first I created *TestSuit* under the project. As first step of *TestSuit* I do SOAP request.

It is possible to enter *TearDown Script* for *TestSuit*:

```
def token = context.expand('${SessionCreateRQ#Response#//*:BinarySecurityToken/text()}')
com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpansionUtils.globalProperties.setPropertyValue('sectoken', token)
```

or like this:

```
def token = context.expand('${SessionCreateRQ#Response#//*:BinarySecurityToken/text()}')
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue('sectoken', token)
```

but subsequent runs doesn't changes value of global variable unless I delete it from `File => Preference` dialog.

So I add second step *Property Transfer* where in GUI I choose name for first request, property *Response*, path language *XPath* and enter expression:

```
//*:BinarySecurityToken/text()
```

As target I choose *Global*, as property my variable name:

[image]

Now when I run *TestSuit* `${#Global#sectoken}` filled with new value and accessible in any SoapUI project!!

- [Get and Set properties API](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html#1-1-Get-and-Set-properties)
- [Transferring properties](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html)
- [Property Expansion in soapUI](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html)